# Is PCA effectively just a rotation of the data, if you were to keep all principal components?

Tags: pca, rotation

If so, why would you apply another rotation after you already found the "variance-maximizing" - and in that sense optimal - rotation.
Wouldn't the second rotation lead to a - again - non-variane-maximizing situation?

Please enlight me.

Comment: Do you know practical cases in which all the components are kept? I believe that the second rotation is most often done *after* eliminating (filtering) the smaller components (slash selecting the larger components) and is most often done for the purpose of easier representation (aligning with more meaningful conceptual axes).

Comment: What you mean by 'second rotation' and 'optimal rotation' is unclear.

Comment: PCA is just the singular value decomposition for a data matrix.  The gyst of SVD is that any matrix (using your language) can be factored as a 'first rotation', followed by a change of scale followed by a second rotation.  So any linear change of variables is just a rotation followed by a scale change.

Comment: So far, I understand PCA with "all components" as a rotation, as my question suggests (= first & optimal rotation)

Comment: There's an internal contradiction in the question.  Keeping all $n$ PCs indeed corresponds to a rotation which is (almost) unique.  But the "variance maximizing rotation" is far from unique: it merely identifies one direction out of an $n-1$ dimensional manifold of possible directions, thereby determining an $(n-1)(n-2)/2$ dimensional manifold of possible rotations. When $n=2$ the first PC determines both PCs, but for $n\gt 2$ the first PC does not fully determine a rotation.